# RichTextBox EnableAutoDragDrop=true requires CTRL key pressed when dropping a ListBox item?

Tags: richtextbox

Not sure how to get around a problem of having to use the CTRL key when dropping a ListBox item into a RichTextBox with EnableAutoDragDrop=true...

Dropping into a TextBox with AllowDrop=true works without the CTRL key.

Using VS2008 .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the previous answer...

Most discussions of this problem on the web focus only on setting AllowDrop = true;, and implementing overrides to the DragDrop and DragEnter events for the Rich Text Box. If you follow their advice and set the cursor on the DragEnter event only, then you will find that you have to press down the Ctrl key to see the cursor you chose.

You can easily remove the need to press the Ctrl key while dragging.

Implement the DragOver event in addition to DragEnter. In this handler, repeat the same logic you used in DragEnter, to select again the cursor you want to show. Here is a simple example just to force it to show the Copy cursor, independent of whether the Ctrl key is pressed or not.

```
private void RichTextBox1_DragOver ( object sender, DragEventArgs e )
{
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works OK in VS2005/2008:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_26532918.html

You need DragDrop and Dragover in your RichTextBox.